# AngularJs ng-repeat add Color to the largest value of the cell in the respected column

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs, 
and do not know how to accomplish this.

I would like to add color to the member with the biggest Score, Missed, field Goal percentage.
is this possible?
[image: the sample table]

is there a way to change the color of value to green of the member with the largest value of each column.

[image]
like this:(desired result)

this is my html code :

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Members</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Missed</th>
        <th>FG%</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        <td>{{member.name}}</td>
        <td>{{getScore(member.shotMade)}}</td>
        <td>{{getMissed(member.shotMade, member.shotAttemp)}}</td>
        <td>{{getFG(member.shotMade, member.shotAttemp)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.test = "success";
    $scope.members = 
    [
        {name:'Kobe', shotMade:23, shotAttemp:44},
        {name:'lebron', shotMade:21, shotAttemp:33},
        {name:'Jordan', shotMade:32, shotAttemp:43},
        {name:'Hakeem', shotMade:20, shotAttemp:21},
    ]
    $scope.getScore = (made)=> made * 2;
    $scope.getMissed = (made, attemp) => attemp - made;
    $scope.getFG = (made, attemp) => (made / attemp) * 10000;
});
```

is there a way to do this with angularjs or Javascript?

Comment: It is not angular specific. You need to try Math.max() function of JavaScript to get max value of a column and highlight all cells in that column with max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.members = [
    { name: 'Kobe', shotMade: 23, shotAttemp: 44 },
    { name: 'lebron', shotMade: 21, shotAttemp: 33 },
    { name: 'Jordan', shotMade: 32, shotAttemp: 43 },
    { name: 'Hakeem', shotMade: 20, shotAttemp: 21 }
  ]
  var getScore = (made) => made * 2;
  var getMissed = (made, attemp) => attemp - made;
  var getFG = (made, attemp) => (made / attemp) * 10000;
  
  $scope.maxScore = 0;
  $scope.maxMissed = 0;
  $scope.maxFG = 0;
  for (var member of $scope.members) {
    member.score = getScore(member.shotMade);
    if (member.score > $scope.maxScore)
      $scope.maxScore = member.score;

    member.missed = getMissed(member.shotMade, member.shotAttemp);
    if (member.missed > $scope.maxMissed)
      $scope.maxMissed = member.missed;

    member.fg = getFG(member.shotMade, member.shotAttemp);
    if (member.fg > $scope.maxFG)
      $scope.maxFG = member.fg;
  }
});
```

```css
.maxGreen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <th>Members</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Missed</th>
      <th>FG%</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
      <td>{{member.name}}</td>
      <td ng-class='{maxGreen: member.score == maxScore}'>{{member.score}}</td>
      <td ng-class='{maxGreen: member.missed == maxMissed }'>{{member.missed}}</td>
      <td ng-class='{maxGreen: member.fg == maxFG}'>{{member.fg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's throw an error :member is not defined, the "var member"